# bootstrap tagsinput with typeaheadjs using an array of objects

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

I'm trying to get tagsinput to work with typeahead. I have an array of objects as the datasource. The value of 'label' should be the one searched and displayed, and the value of 'value' should be the submitted value(s). Pretty straight forward, one would think.

But the typeahead-menu is not shown when I use this array of objects.

```
[...]
<select name="users" multiple class="auto_users" ></select>
[...]
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var users = [{label: "Super 1", value: "8"},{label: "Super2", value: "9"},{label: "Almindelig1", value: "10"},{label: "Almindelig2", value: "11"}];

    var users = new Bloodhound({
      datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
      local: users
    });

    users.initialize();

    $('.auto_users').tagsinput({
      typeaheadjs: {
        name: 'users',
        displayKey: 'label',
        valueKey: 'value',
        source: users.ttAdapter()
      }
    });
  });

</script>
```

If I change it to a simple array of strings and remove displayKey/valueKey settings, it works, but obviously without submitting the id's from the original object-array.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, in order to be able to use bloodhound, typeahead js from **[here](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/)** should be used.

Secondly, `datumTokenizer` was not configured properly. It should look like this

`datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('label'),`

Here is a demo **https://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/aawmp3np/47/**

---

### UPDATE

itemValue and itemText options should do it.

```
itemValue: 'value',
itemText: 'label',
```

Full snippet

```
$('select').tagsinput({
    itemValue: 'value',
    itemText: 'label',
    typeaheadjs: {
        name: 'users',
        displayKey: 'label',
        source: users.ttAdapter()
    }
});
```

Updated demo **https://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/aawmp3np/48/**

Comment: Thanks. In your demo the 'value' ends up in the input, but I'd like to have the 'label' there.

Comment: @henrik242: updated the demo. You had to update the valueKey to `valueKey: 'label',` Please mark it as answered if it is solved so that other users can also benefit

Comment: Your example shows a text input. What I'd like is to use a select with multiple, since I need the list of id's (values) to be submitted. Even if I change to valueKey: 'label' (which sounds counter-intuitive to me) the label string does not appear in the input field.

Comment: I forgot to update the link in my demo. Check now you should see the label appearing in the input field.

Comment: sorry - changing to ```valueKey: label``` did indeed work, but it's still not quite what I need, since the id's are not submitted.

Comment: thanks - so far so so good. What I still need is to display the label while submitting the values.

Comment: Something like this should do it I guess https://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/aawmp3np/48/ should work. Also updated my answer